# getBoundingClientRect() inconsistency

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an issue with DOMnode.getBoundingClientRect() because the data returned is not consistent. I am using `windows.onload` (for the lack of a better option) to trigger my function which takes a `getBoundingClientRect().height` of an element to do some calculation with it.

Issue is, the height of the element is not always consistent. `window.onload` even should fire last in the page lifecycle as far as i know and both the content and the stylesheets and external resources should be loaded by then, however the page apparently still hasn't rendered it properly yet since I sometimes get height values of like 400, 528, 630 and sometimes its correct (700) for an element I am trying to read.

Thoughts?

Is there some other way to detect when the a `div` (or a page) has had itself rendered fully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window`'s `load` does indeed mean all resources (including stylesheets and images) have either loaded or failed, but:

1. It doesn't necessarily mean the browser has completely rendered the result, and
2. If other JavaScript code is running on `load` and changes things, those changes may also impact what you're seeing (of course)

Solving #2 will be specific to the code running, but if your problem is just #1, a short `setTimeout` should fix it:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Your code here
    }, 60);
};
```

You may have to play with the delay. 0 tends to work for Chrome, but Firefox tends to want values in the at least 50-60ms range.

Or possibly just `requestAnimationFrame` may be sufficient:

```
window.onload = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // Your code here
    });
};
```

You might combine one or the other of the above with a check that `document.readyState` is `"complete"`, since that's [the very last thing the browser does](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-end) (other than JavaScript code set to run on completion, of course). So for instance:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function ready() {
        // Your code here
    }
    function checkReady() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            ready();
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkReady, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I will try to do with requestAnimationFrame, since Timeout with a constant is something i'd really like to avoid. It is just so weird that there is no event that means stuff is rendered and we have to flock to this kind of an approach :S

Out of curiosity, how'd you solve #2, if its simple, and not "do a call from the end of those other functions".

Comment: @Dellirium: It's fine for certain limited use cases. I've added a note to the above. `load` really is meant to be the final event of the load cycle, although I'm told sometimes you'll still see `document.readyState` being `"interactive"` when it fires.

Comment: I tried with the `requestAnimationFrame` no positive results. And upon further inspection it turns out it might be a script that is causing the issue. At the bottom of the `<body>` tag there is a script tag and it adds some `<link>` tags to the page, linking to external css files, which I assume is not being waited for to finish before windows load is fired, is my only solution in that case a `setTimeout` I assume?

Comment: Okay so `setTimeout(function(){}, 100)` was enough of a delay to solve the issue, i hope that in some next iteration of js they will implement a way to get around this, it just feels so dirty doing it this way. Thanks for the help @T.J. Crowder, right as always.

Comment: @Dellirium: Right, `load` won't wait for those dynamically-added stylesheets, because of the way they're added. Beware that 100ms may not be enough if there's network congestion, etc. The only way to be sure is to hook into events on those `link` elements ([more here](https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/)), but even that's going to be unreliable because you can't know for sure the events haven't fired before you hooked them, and `link` lacks the equivalent of `img`'s `complete` flag. *"i hope that in some next iteration of js..."* Being pedantic: DOM, not JavaScript. :-)